# Solspace Freeform (free version) {freeform:all_form_fields} not working

Tags: solspace-freeform

I am looking at the Solspace Freeform (free version) documentation and **I see this**:

```
{freeform:all_form_fields}
<p>
    <label>{freeform:field_label}</label>
    {freeform:field_output}
    {if freeform:field_type == 'text'}
        hello!
    {/if}
</p>
{/freeform:all_form_fields}
```

I am using this in my code:

```
{exp:freeform:entries form_name="expert_request"} 

    {freeform:all_form_fields}
        <label>{freeform:field_label}</label>
        {freeform:field_output}
    {/freeform:all_form_fields}

{/exp:freeform:entries}
```

And this is what outputs on my site:

```
{freeform:field_label}
{freeform:field_output}
{freeform:field_label}
{freeform:field_output}
{freeform:field_label}
{freeform:field_output}
```

Can anyone tell me why the output on the tags is returning nothing? Thanks for any help.

***~DVL***

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to ensure you have created your fields and connect them to the correct freeform "form" - in your case it'd be "expert_request".